# Selenium, Python, Chrome Driver -Send_Keys

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

could someone kindly point out to me where I'm going wrong please?

I've looked up the documentation and I thought I set it up correctly but keep getting the error:

```
line 29, in <module>
    username.send_keys(cred_username)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Currently I can:

- Load and access the page
- get past the security wall my browser throws up
- load up the log in screen, but am not able to input my credentials.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

cred_username = "username"
cred_password = "password"

s_1=Service("my driver location")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s_1)

driver.get("https:website")

# Hurdle 01 Start : get past security step.
advanced = driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button")
advanced.click()

proceed = driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link")
proceed.click()
# Hurdle 01 Finish : 

# Hurdle 02 Start : logging in
username = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "idUsername")
username.clear()
username.send_keys(cred_username)
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "idPassword")
password.clear()
password.send_keys(cred_password)
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(99)
```

I've tried setting it as a string but get the same error.
I've also tried a variation of "send_keys_to_element(element, *keys_to_send)"
I've also tried setting an xPATH but get the same results.

If anyone can point out where I'm going wrong or direct to a web page that explains where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it, thanks for having a look.

I thought what I had written would allow me to simply input my log-in details at this stage so I can then access a page which would allow me to upload a document. This is the only part of the process that requires input from a keyboard.

**Update from answer:**

Thanks for the answer [Prophet], I've removed the 's' as you suggest and tried using the XPATH again, but now have this error come up, I feel I'm close but there's something obvious I'm missing.

```
  File "/Users/jace/Desktop/Filing_Cabinet/Python_Folder/my_phone_config01.py", line 27
    username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id="Username"]")
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
[Finished in 25ms with exit code 1]
```

**Update from comment:**
[pitcture of the inspection page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7rhV.png)

**Resolved, Final update**

Prophet had pointed out I may of needed to wait for the page to load fully, hence why I was having a hard time finding the element to send keys to.

Adding a wait allowed the element to actually load for my script to locate it.

```
# Step 03 Start : logging in
try: 
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='idUsername']"))
    )
    username.send_keys(cred_username)
 
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='idPassword']"))
    )
    password.send_keys(cred_password)
    password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# Step 03 End : need to add wait commands/let the page load.
finally:
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: their is a 's' in `driver.find_elements(By.ID, "idUsername")` , it should be in `find_element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is here: `username = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "idUsername")`
You need to use `find_element` method, not `find_elements` since `find_element` returns a web element object so you can apply `send_keys` method on it, while `find_elements` returns a **list** of web element and you can not apply `send_keys` method on a list.
**UPD**
As about your additional issue.
The following XPath expression can be fixed as following:

```py
username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='Username']")
```

Or

```py
username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="Username"]')
```

The rule is simple: in case you enclose the string with `"`, the internal strings should be enclosed with `'` and wise versa.

Comment: Hi Prophet, could I bother you and get for your two cents on my update please?

Comment: Sure. But tomorrow

Comment: Thanks Prophet, can't seem to locate the element without it being a list, when I remove the 's' I get an error saying no element can be found but when I keep the 's' it gives me the same message before, as you explained I can't send keys to a list but I can't seem to locate the element without it being one.

Comment: Well, This means you are using a wrong locator or page is still not loaded. We can't debug this issue since you not shared the link

Comment: does this help at all? it's to access a phone on my net work so didn't think it would be helpful to share the site as no one can access externally

Comment: AAHHH!! I needed to add a sleep command!! you were right!

Comment: Thank you! sorry for being a newb about this! I added a 5 second sleep commans before the logging step could proceed and it found it!

Comment: Right. But it's better to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits, not a hardcoded sleeps

Comment: I'll add that to my script, I think I saw a tutorial showing me that, thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: You are welcome. In case you have any more problems - don't hesitate to ask here. Just provide as many as possible details about your code, the error you facing etc.